# Is this function on-to-one?

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus

This is the question http://puu.sh/rkEDE/7101027601.png

I answered "No it is not" and I got it wrong. I thought since the function increases until 3.5 and then decreases, it has a concave, meaning if you do a horizontal line test, it will cross at two points

Comment: Please include your question in the body of the post instead of in an external image.

Comment: Also update your title to include the specific function in question.

Answer (score 2):

I think you are meant to take the table as exhaustive making it easy to check it is 1-1

Comment: In other words, the function is not defined in the interval $[1,6]$, but rather at the set $\{1,2,3,4,5,6\}$.

Comment: @Fimpellizieri yes, it seems OP assumed it was continuous